# How to divide screen in Xamarin.ios like we divides in uwp by Grid

Tags: xamarin.ios

Hi i am a window mobile app developer and just 1 day before i started to work with xamarin ios. I wanna know that how the screen or grid is divided into percentage in xamarin ios so that the same app can run in 4 inch as well as 6 inch mobile or at least in one of them with predetermined location of UI elements. 
    It can be easily achieve in UWP by the Grid RowDefinition and Grid    ColumDefinition tags like below.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Screen Devidation Demo in %" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row = "1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text = "Save" Grid.Column ="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Xamarin.iOS (not Forms), you are likely looking for a *Collection View*: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_collection_views/

If you're building an iOS app with Xamarin.Forms, you can create the same grid with XAML: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/

Depending on the complexity of your app, Forms may be a good approach for you - you'll be able to apply your experience with UWP nicely to your iOS app.